# Ubuntu SDK on Open Suse

Tags: installation

From where can I download Ubuntu SDK for mobile application development? I can not find any links to operate it on OpenSuse.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it doesn't support anything other than Ubuntu (it is the Ubuntu Linux SDK after all). You can install it by downloading the .deb for it here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/devel/ubuntu-sdk and then using this command in Terminal:

```
alien -r <FILE>.deb
```

[This isn't recommended by the users I got the command from](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/434672-installing-deb-packages-opensuse.html)